# Behat/Mink: how can I evaluate a xml response

Tags: testing, symfony, bdd, behat

I am trying to test a RSS feed via Behat/Mink. Unfortunately I am getting an error message all the time:

> The current node list is empty.

Does anyone know how to test an XML response (search for a string in xml) via Behat/Mink?

**edit**

I need to find some way, and best would be to get it running with Behat/Mink.
But if thats not possible at all, I can live with a workaround too.
An example on how to do that would be great!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your FeatureContext.php file You can get raw content by

```
$xml = $this->getSession()->getDriver()->getContent();
```

And then you can use Regex/DomDocument to test the returned xml content.

Comment: This call above is currently throwing the following error for me: "Tag matching xpath "//html" not found. (Behat\Mink\Exception\ElementNotFoundException)" Digging deeper. Will update if I resolve it.

Comment: The answer below that mentioned `file_get_contents()` resolved the issue for me.

On the assumption that a previous step had sent you to the XML path you can fetch that like this:

`$xml = file_get_contents($this->getSession()->getCurrentUrl());`

`getCurrentUrl()` will return the full URL with the domain name in place as well even if a previous step directed you to a path without the domain name.

Answer (score 3):

Mink is a browser emulation abstraction layer. Some browsers can read RSS, some can't. Parsing custom XML is not Mink responsibility. Use combination of Behat + Web crawler + DomDocument (or any PHP RSS parser) for that.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! Could you describe how I could add this functionality to my feature-context (which in my case extends MinkContext)? I am not talking about how to parse xml, but how to retrieve the content of the http response. All I have in my context is session::getPage, which does not help me...

Comment: @stoefln use any http client or even file_get_contents() to fetch the rss feed.

Comment: @JakubZalas ah ok, just found out that i can get the current url with $this->getSession()->getCurrentUrl() in the context. that could work... if you wanna create an answer, I can give you the bounty for that...

Answer (score 2):

As @everzet mentioned, Mink is not the best tool for the job, since it's a browser emulator rather than an http client.

You're not limited to Mink though and you could use any PHP http client (like [guzzle](https://packagist.org/packages/guzzle/http) or [buzz](https://packagist.org/packages/kriswallsmith/buzz)) or even `file_get_contents()` to fetch the rss feed.

Comment: This was the simplest fix for me.  In case it is helpful, the `getCurrentUrl()` call is useful here if it was already set in an earlier step.

`$xml = file_get_contents($this->getSession()->getCurrentUrl());`